# Angular project doesn't work after update from 11 to 12 version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, angular-cli

I followed this steps to update my angular project.

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm uninstall @angular/cli@latest @angular/core@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest @angular/core@latest
```

After that I deleted my node_modules directory and I executed
`npm ci`

And finally
`npm install node@latest`

After all of that I started the project
`ng serve --host 192.168.1.155`

But I got the following errors:

```html
Build at: 2021-06-06T13:14:39.792Z - Hash: 881d2a0f5195ee376bc8 - Time: 293719ms

Warning: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'ngx-localforage'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\src\app\components\dashboardprincipal\dashboardprincipal.component.ts depends on 'chart.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\src\app\services\file.service.ts depends on 'rxjs/Rx'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\fontawesome-free\css\all.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\tempusdominus-bootstrap-4\css\tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\https:\code.ionicframework.com\ionicons\2.0.1\css\ionicons.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\icheck-bootstrap\icheck-bootstrap.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\datatables-bs4\css\dataTables.bootstrap4.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\overlayScrollbars\css\OverlayScrollbars.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\select2\css\select2.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\select2-bootstrap4-theme\select2-bootstrap4.min.css

3mWarning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\daterangepicker\daterangepicker.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\dist\css\adminlte.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\dist\css\adminlte.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\summernote\summernote-bs4.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\toastr\toastr.min.css

Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\bootstrap4-duallistbox\bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css



Error: node_modules/ngx-localforage/dist/src/localforage.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolmanager/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta'.

5     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<LocalForageModule, never, never, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ngx-localforage/dist/src/localforage.service.d.ts:16:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolmanager/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'
has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

16     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LocalForageService, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ngx-localforage/dist/src/localforage.service.d.ts:17:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolmanager/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

17     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<LocalForageService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


assets/plugins/sweetalert2-theme-bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.scss - Error: assets/plugins/sweetalert2-theme-bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\sweetalert2-theme-bootstrap-4\bootstrap-4.scss:14:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/plugins/sweetalert2-theme-bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.scss:14,4]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.decl (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:201:16)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:115:18)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/irs.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/irs.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\irs.less:1:1: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/irs.less:1,1]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/_base.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/_base.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\_base.less:4:5: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/_base.less:4,5]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/big.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/big.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\big.less:33:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/big.less:33,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/flat.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/flat.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\flat.less:30:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/flat.less:30,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/modern.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/modern.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\modern.less:30:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/modern.less:30,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/round.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/round.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\round.less:33:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/round.less:33,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/sharp.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/sharp.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\sharp.less:32:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/sharp.less:32,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/square.less - Error: assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/square.less from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\assets\plugins\ion-rangeslider\less\skins\square.less:33:8: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/plugins/ion-rangeslider/less/skins/square.less:33,8]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:132:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\utils.js:58:61)
    at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:262:128
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:31
    at run (C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:23:43)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanager\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:45:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 192.168.1.155:4200, open your browser on http://192.168.1.155:4200/ **
```

Here is my angular version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSXr9.png)

Node version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAyGD.png)

My package.json

```js
{
    "name": "schoolmanager",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "postinstall": "ngcc"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.0.3",
        "@angular/animations": "^12.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.3",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
        "angular-dual-listbox": "^6.0.0",
        "bn-ng-idle": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
        "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
        "dexie": "^3.0.3",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
        "jquery": "^3.5.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "localforage": "^1.9.0",
        "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
        "ngx-localforage": "^9.0.1",
        "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
        "node": "^16.1.0",
        "react-flag-icon-css": "^1.0.25",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.3",
        "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
        "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.3",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.2.4"
    }
}
```

```
enter code here
```

npm version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEKpg.png)

Can someone help me, please? Now I'm not able to run the project.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The angular team does a lot of work to help with version migrations, and has a useful [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) that I've found to be (while not perfect), quite useful in updating my apps over many major versions.

I note that in their [instructions for updating from 11 to 12](https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-12.0), they indicate that you should:

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12
```

I would suggest you revert your changes-in-progress and take advantage of these resources to effect the update.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reverting to version 11 - Struggled with a lot of errors when I upgraded to version 12 especially with the scss, I ended up commenting out some of my stuff... v12 also takes a while to build too.

If you are on version 11 - don't be too quick to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `yarn.lock` and install it again
you can refer this link also,
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock/